# Amazon S3 - Edit uploaded Images

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, multer

**OVERVIEW:** I'm using Amazon S3 to let users upload images. I've been working on an edit route so that users can edit their images after they've uploaded them. I'm doing this via a PUT route. This is my current solution. It works as far as overriding the current images.

**PROBLEM:** If a user selects zero new images it overwrites the old images with blank filepaths. Aka no images show up after editing. The same thing happens if a user only tries to edit one image, that one image will update but the others are overwritten with blank filepaths so no images show.

**QUESTION:** What is the correct way to let a user edit an image using Amazon S3 and Multer-S3?

Thanks for any help! :)

```
app.put("/:id", function(req, res){

          upload(req,res,function(err) {
            if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/')
            }

          var filepath = undefined;

          var filepath2 = undefined;

          var filepath3 = undefined;

        if(req.files[0]) {
            filepath = req.files[0].key;
        } 

          if(req.files[1]) {
            filepath2 = req.files[1].key;
        } 

         if(req.files[2]) {
            filepath3 = req.files[2].key;
        } 


        var image = filepath;
        var image2 = filepath2;
        var image3 = filepath3;


        var newData = {image: image, image2: image2, image3: image3}
        Rental.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: newData}, 
        function(err, rentals){

            if(err){
                req.flash("error", err.message);
                res.redirect("back");
            } else {

                req.flash("success","Successfully Updated!");
                res.redirect("/rentals/" + rental._id);

            }
    });
    });
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should validate the user input before calling the downstream updates.

You should not need to call `Rental.findByIdAndUpdate` if the values have not been populated correctly (as there is nothing to update).

I can't offer more help without seeing the code for `Rental`.